# Dependencies not found that are included in CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake, box2d

I've created a new project with a CMakeLists.txt and vcpkg in Windows 11 with CLion.

I would like to add Box2D, OpenGL, GLUT, GLEW, and SFML

To do so I've cloned vcpkg in the project directory and added a vcpkg.json.

**vcpkg.json**

```
{
  "name" : "example-project",
  "version-string" : "0.0.1",
  "license" : "MIT",
  "dependencies" : [ 
    "box2d", 
    "sfml", 
    "opengl", 
    "freeglut", 
    "glew"
  ]
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

# Setup vcpkg script with CMake (note: should be placed before project() call)
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake CACHE STRING "Vcpkg toolchain file")

project(ExampleApp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)

find_package(SFML COMPONENTS system window graphics network audio CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(box2d CONFIG REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)
find_package(GLUT REQUIRED)
find_package(GLEW REQUIRED)

include_directories(SFML)
include_directories(box2d)
include_directories(OpenGL)
include_directories(OpenGL/include) # OpenGL/include has to contain the required OpenGL's .h files
include_directories(OpenGL/lib) # OpenGL/lib has to contain the required OpenGL's .lib files

set(ExampleApp_SourceFiles example/files)

add_executable(ExampleApp ${ExampleApp_SourceFiles})

target_include_directories(ExampleApp
        PUBLIC
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include>
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
        PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src
        ${_VCPKG_INSTALLED_DIR}/include
        )

target_include_directories(ExampleApp PRIVATE ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(ExampleApp PRIVATE GLEW::GLEW)
target_link_libraries(ExampleApp PRIVATE ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(ExampleApp PRIVATE sfml-system PRIVATE sfml-network PRIVATE  sfml-graphics PRIVATE sfml-window)
target_link_libraries(ExampleApp PRIVATE FastNoise)
target_link_libraries(ExampleApp PRIVATE box2d::box2d)
```

I've added this CMake option for CLion as mentioned in the vcpkg documentation.

```
-G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/Users/micha/CLionProjects/cmake-vcpkg-example/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
```

After building this (Using the MinGW Toolchain and Generator) I get errors that files aren't found in box2d and sfml (Likely in the other dependencies too).

**Error**

```
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.1.5\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\ExampleApp.dir/objects.a(Chunk.cpp.obj): in function `Chunk::~Chunk()':
```

**Chunk**

```
  // undefined reference
  simulation->game->world->DestroyBody(body);
```

This method worked fine for adding the `fmt` and `Catch2` libraries but I can't get it to find these other libraries.

What else do I need to do to use these dependencies? I've spent days on this now and can't find any similar examples.

Comment: Compilation of which **source file** causes these errors? Please, add **complete error message** to the question post.

Comment: You **privately** link `ExampleLib` library with SFML. That is, `ExampleApp` executable doesn't obtain that linkage.

Comment: I've removed the `ExampleLib` now. It successfully builds but there is a linking error as it can't find the Box2D files still. Anywhere Box2D is used it outputs an undefined reference. I've updated the question.
What is the correct method of linking the files?